# Python Regex to Find Special Characters and characters in between

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I have a csv file that looks like the following

```
Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;2842.020;2843.270;Unknown;; tecnici delle societ…
Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;2903.310;2906.360;Unknown;; pu• avere un profilo specifico
Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;2745.860;2749.060;Unknown;; Š quadruplicato rispetto al 1967.
Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;1023.580;1026.250;Unknown;; monitoraggio fosse completo e cosŤ via.
Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;708.870;711.290;Unknown;; Non solo un ponte, ma qualcosa di pi—.
Porta-a-Porta-d605218c-b8c5-4b3b-9086-b83e4c958bf5;4199.210;4200.540;Unknown;; piů straziante.
Porta-a-Porta-c28a23f4-d7b0-4624-8b49-72ba25be653e;4702.720;4703.900;Unknown;; tant'č che questo ragazzo
Presa-Diretta-Burocrazia-al-potere-ce58265f-da04-4b19-a1ad-2746830cac0a;4229.110;4232.130;Unknown;; a un testo di 13 pagine con 7/8.000 parole.<
Presa-Diretta-Burocrazia-al-potere-ce58265f-da04-4b19-a1ad-2746830cac0a;4541.560;4543.100;Unknown;; sei/otto ore al giorno.<
PresaDiretta-Il-capitale-naturale-8f39ea4f-a5fb-4c93-a504-a04d6482c086;1938.730;1941.830;Unknown;; abbattere i cervi.> Senza di loro, questa terra sarebbe
Quante-storie-15aef095-7ba8-4237-af6e-aded20d1d40a;19.920;22.630;Unknown;; questa puntata {an2}che ha come ospite una
Quante-storie-15aef095-7ba8-4237-af6e-aded20d1d40a;64.080;68.090;Unknown;; {an2}Sì, perché c'è come un ritegno a venire in una
Quante-storie-200b0694-7d54-4b5c-af5a-b54cae157ffd;446.730;447.790;Unknown;; della nostra Patria. {an2}[LA
Quante-storie-2583a3a2-2e8c-4589-bede-933736b65043;1781.910;1783.030;Unknown;; UDIBILI]
Porta-a-Porta-3b4b81d5-2f0f-4e51-9c29-00f9a2aa4444;4159.470;4160.890;Unknown;; bianca torneremo.#
Porta-a-Porta-3b4b81d5-2f0f-4e51-9c29-00f9a2aa4444;4196.930;4198.230;Unknown;; del sole#
```

and I am trying to spot unnecessary characters that should not belong in this file such as `<` or `{` or `{an2}` or `[` and so on.

This is the regex I have right now and does the job well except it does not catch some cases like `{an2}` or `#` as described above. I would like to find everything including `an2` and leave every Italian characters as is.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9;'"\.\- ,\?:£\]\[\/()%!èàéùòìíŕěúůňčÂŤŠÈÉôü&+<>#@$%^…—‚–]
```

Let me know if there is any easier way to solve this problem.

Comment: You can add `{an2}` in regex

Comment: @ma_dev_15 this regex ignores the characters inside. adding ```{an2}``` would make it invisible from my regex. I would like to find\spot them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that, maybe we would find those undesired parts, then replace with an empty string, with some expressions similar to:

```
{.+?}|[\[\]<>]
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"{.+?}|[\[\]<>]"

test_str = ("Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;2842.020;2843.270;Unknown;; tecnici delle societ…\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;2903.310;2906.360;Unknown;; pu• avere un profilo specifico\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;2745.860;2749.060;Unknown;; Š quadruplicato rispetto al 1967.\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;1023.580;1026.250;Unknown;; monitoraggio fosse completo e cosŤ via.\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-d87134d1-e2bd-426b-b1f6-90d8dca68855;708.870;711.290;Unknown;; Non solo un ponte, ma qualcosa di pi—.\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-d605218c-b8c5-4b3b-9086-b83e4c958bf5;4199.210;4200.540;Unknown;; piů straziante.\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-c28a23f4-d7b0-4624-8b49-72ba25be653e;4702.720;4703.900;Unknown;; tant'č che questo ragazzo\n"
    "Presa-Diretta-Burocrazia-al-potere-ce58265f-da04-4b19-a1ad-2746830cac0a;4229.110;4232.130;Unknown;; a un testo di 13 pagine con 7/8.000 parole.<\n"
    "Presa-Diretta-Burocrazia-al-potere-ce58265f-da04-4b19-a1ad-2746830cac0a;4541.560;4543.100;Unknown;; sei/otto ore al giorno.<\n"
    "PresaDiretta-Il-capitale-naturale-8f39ea4f-a5fb-4c93-a504-a04d6482c086;1938.730;1941.830;Unknown;; abbattere i cervi.> Senza di loro, questa terra sarebbe\n"
    "Quante-storie-15aef095-7ba8-4237-af6e-aded20d1d40a;19.920;22.630;Unknown;; questa puntata {an2}che ha come ospite una\n"
    "Quante-storie-15aef095-7ba8-4237-af6e-aded20d1d40a;64.080;68.090;Unknown;; {an2}Sì, perché c'è come un ritegno a venire in una\n"
    "Quante-storie-200b0694-7d54-4b5c-af5a-b54cae157ffd;446.730;447.790;Unknown;; della nostra Patria. {an2}[LA\n"
    "Quante-storie-2583a3a2-2e8c-4589-bede-933736b65043;1781.910;1783.030;Unknown;; UDIBILI]\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-3b4b81d5-2f0f-4e51-9c29-00f9a2aa4444;4159.470;4160.890;Unknown;; bianca torneremo.#\n"
    "Porta-a-Porta-3b4b81d5-2f0f-4e51-9c29-00f9a2aa4444;4196.930;4198.230;Unknown;; del sole#")

subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HF8s47/1/)